# DevStack: error on instance creation

Tags: deployment, openstack, devstack

I have problems in installing correctly DevStack on my computer.

**The procedure I follow**

I started by cloning the repository from here:

```
git clone https://git.openstack.org/openstack-dev/devstack
```

Then, I created my `local.conf` file in the `/devstack` folder, as follows:

```
[[local|localrc]]
ADMIN_PASSWORD=<my admin password>
DATABASE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
RABBIT_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
SERVICE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
FLOATING_RANGE=<my floating IP range>
HOST_IP=<my IP>
```

Then, I created the `stack` user and logged in with it:

```
devstack/tools/create-stack-user.sh
sudo su stack
sudo chown -R stack:stack /home/user/devstack
```

Finally, I started the script with:

```
./stack.sh
```

**The problem**

At this point, I can access to the DevStack dashboard and start using it.

I go to the `Instances` tab (in the `admin` project), I select `Launch Instance` and I set up it like this:

- Instance name: `hello`
- Create new volume: `No`
- Image allocated: `cirros-0.3.4-x86_64-uec`
- Flavor: `m1.tiny`

However, this creates an instance with an error:

[image: error]

This obviously happens in any project

I tried to have details on the error by doing:

```
cd devstack
source openrc admin admin
nova show hello
```

and what I get as fault error is:

```
{"message": "No valid host was found. There are not enough hosts available.", "code": 500, "details": "  File \"/opt/stack/nova/nova/conductor/manager.py\", line 471, in build_instances
```

When I list the active services with `nova service-list`, I get:

```
+----+------------------+------------------+----------+---------+-------+----------------------------+-----------------+
| Id | Binary           | Host             | Zone     | Status  | State | Updated_at                 | Disabled Reason |
+----+------------------+------------------+----------+---------+-------+----------------------------+-----------------+
| 3  | nova-conductor   |openstack | internal | enabled | up    | 2016-07-27T08:37:52.000000 | -               |
| 5  | nova-network     |openstack | internal | enabled | up    | 2016-07-27T08:37:57.000000 | -               |
| 6  | nova-scheduler   |openstack | internal | enabled | up    | 2016-07-27T08:37:52.000000 | -               |
| 7  | nova-consoleauth |openstack | internal | enabled | up    | 2016-07-27T08:37:52.000000 | -               |
+----+------------------+------------------+----------+---------+-------+----------------------------+-----------------+
```

while executing `nova hypervisor-stats` gets me to:

```
+----------------------+-------+
| Property             | Value |
+----------------------+-------+
| count                | 0     |
| current_workload     | 0     |
| disk_available_least | 0     |
| free_disk_gb         | 0     |
| free_ram_mb          | 0     |
| local_gb             | 0     |
| local_gb_used        | 0     |
| memory_mb            | 0     |
| memory_mb_used       | 0     |
| running_vms          | 0     |
| vcpus                | 0     |
| vcpus_used           | 0     |
+----------------------+-------+
```

**What I tried to do afterwards**

Since `nova-compute` is not listed in the set of active services, I tried to launch it manually:

```
sudo nohup nova-compute &
```

After this, I created an instance, that was created with no error, was in boot phase, but after two minutes the machine became unreachable and would not answer to ping requests. So, since this required a reboot, and DevStack does not survive to reboots, I lost the possibility of trying further actions.

---

Is there any way for you to give me details on this error? I tried to fix it by reinstalling from scratch DevStack, by building a new machine and install it on it, but it did not solve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you don't have enough resources allocated to create new guests. Check `ram_allocation_ratio` in nova.conf.

The other possibility is that your networking configuration is incorrect.